# String to LocalDateTime conversion : java.time.format.DateTimeParseException

Tags: java, dateformatter

I am using the below code to convert a date in String :

```
    String strDate="Thu Aug 09 16:01:46 IST 2018";        
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(strDate,formatter);
```

I am getting the below exception :

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Thu Aug 09 16:01:46 IST 2018' could not be parsed at index 0
```

The format in the variable 'strDate' will be same and cannot be modified as i will be getting that from a different application

Comment: I need to convert the input string to 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' format.

Comment: The pattern of input string should match it with the parser, once you get the date from the parser, then again convert the date into your desired pattern. Its a two step process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format for your input string would be : `E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy`. Below code should work without any error

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String strDate = "Thu Aug 09 16:01:46 IST 2018";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(strDate, formatter);
}
```